# Modifying parent scope for Special Variables within Angular expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm developing a colorpicker with Angular and trying to incorporate some of the ideas I've seen elsewhere in order to write the expression that will be called whenever a user picks a color.

```
<color-picker on-pick='something($color)'></color-picker>
```

I've noticed that all of the built in directives use this style of scope binding, rather than say for instance, passing the function straight onto the scope.

```
<color-picker on-pick='something'></color-picker>
```

An example of this style is ngRepeat:

```
<li ng-repeat='item in items' ng-bind='$index'></li>
```

I understand that the `something($color)` expression will evaluated with the parent scope, rather than the scope of the directive itself, meaning that the `$color` property would have to be available on the parent scope in order to be correctly evaluated.

However, if the directive has an isolate scope, it won't see the parent. Even if it could, I don't want to clobber a `$color` variable into that scope.

In a similar vein, I've seen somewhere that a scope binding using `&prop` will evaluate the expression within the parent scope, rather than the directive's scope. However, if that is the case, how can it be possible to make calls like `on-pick='something($color)'` as the $color property comes from the directive's scope, whereas the `something` function would be on the parent scope?

The Angular documentation for ngRepeat refers to these variables as 'special variables', however a look at the source shows that they are assigned onto a scope generated from some system of block mapping. I struggled to follow past there at a quick glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `"&"` binding for your directive's isolate scope.

So, for example, if you have the following directive:

```
app.directive("random", function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      onClick: "&"
    },
    template: "<button ng-click='genRandom()'>generate random</button>",
    link: function(scope){
      scope.genRandom = function(){
        scope.onClick({num: Math.random()});
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Then, in the outer scope, you could do:

```
<random on-click="doSomethingWithRandom(num)"></random>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YuHphJxgBTvlesRswU7X?p=preview)

In other words, when you call the `"&"` handler, you pass it an object where every "key" is a variable that could be referenced from outside (but only in the context of invoking the handler function) and every "value" - is the value set to that variable.

Comment: Ah, yeah. So when you call a property bound to the scope with `&` then the first argument is a scope object? Which could just be the directive scope?

Comment: The first (and only?) argument is an object of parameters that you are passing to the handler function. You should be able to pass the entire directive's scope

Comment: @DanPrince, did the answer address your question otherwise?

Comment: Yep, forgot I had left this hanging. Sorry! Do you have a reference resource for dispelling the different types of scope bindings? The Angular docs are kinda weird to read and lots of the other articles I've seen are flat out wrong.

Comment: [Documentation of $compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) is up to date and seems complete